# Is the size/age of the universe dependent on your velocity?

Tags: cosmology, reference-frames, time, universe, observers

As Photons do not experience time or space, then according to my thought experiment, all photons must occupy some kind of singularity as well as what WE observe from earth.
I was also thinking that the faster you travel the smaller the universe becomes and although you experience time, that time is dependent on the observer.
I'm trying to get my head round this (I have no science background)
It appears to me that the universe is at the big bang all the way to what we observe at the same instance

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. In terms of the present value $H_0$ of the Hubble parameter, the age of the universe has the observer-independent definition$$\int_0^1\frac{a\operatorname{d}a}{H_0\sqrt{\Omega_\Lambda a^{1-3w}+\Omega_ka^2+(\Omega_b+\Omega_c)a+\Omega_{\operatorname{rad}}}}$$(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model#Cosmic_expansion_history) for more details).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222484/2451 and links therein.